# VB6 WaveIn API, input stops when I connect with RDP session on Windows 10

Tags: winapi, vb6

I build a application to monitor 24/7 the input level of a soundcard. I use the WaveIn API to get the audio level. This applications works well on Windows 7. On Windows 10 it works well too, only thing is that when I connect with RDP to the Windows 10 machine, the audioinput level 'hangs' to one value.

The application is not hanging. When I start the monitoring again everything works. I tried MSTSC /ADMIN so I be sure that I use the same session.

I think something goes wrong with the WaveIn API I use. Does anybody know something about this issue?

Best Regards,
Nicos

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but try tinkering with the remote audio settings in the RDP connection file (tab "Local resources") and see if that makes a differences.

Comment: [Supported Remote Desktop RDP file settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files#device-redirection). Try to modify the `audiomode:i:value` in the RDP file to `2`.

Comment: Thanks Hel O'Ween and Junjie Zhu! I tryied this but only play options can be modified. Recording settings can't be made. I Think this is not the problem.

Comment: Have you ever checked this recording setting? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYdWT.jpg